# Problem importing FireBase Analytics into Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I have a project at Unity 2019.3 with dotnet 4.x. I am trying to import firebase analicts and I have gotten the following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.Editor.Measurement' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: void Google.EditorMeasurement.set_InstallSourceFilename(string)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Firebase.Editor.AndroidSettingsChecker..cctor () [0x0000c] in Z:\tmp\tmp.SHkOPK7iEJ\firebase\app\client\unity\editor\src\AndroidAPILevelChecker.cs:37

and

> MissingMethodException: void Google.EditorMeasurement.set_InstallSourceFilename(string)

Does anyone have any idea what it could be? Was any library missing? I haven't found reference to this problem anywhere.

Comment: I've just gone through and verified that it's working on my machine (Firebase 6.13.0 and Unity 2019.3.6, MacOS). I would highly recommend re-posting this as an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues). If not, it's still useful to have answers to the questions in the issue template on GitHub (specifically editor version, runtime, &c).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I believe I found the problem, there was a conflict between the Facebook SDK and the FireBase, I'm not sure if it was just that yet, as I'm stuck now in another problem, which is beside the point in this post. I'll get back to you as soon as I have it.

Comment: I'd love to know how you work it out! I can maybe get your solution into the Firebase support playbooks!

Comment: Try this, maybe it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677353/initializationexception-in-unity-firebase

Comment: Just curious, when you imported the sdk, did you run the Play Services Resolver as well? It could be that you're missing some plugins that should be included in your Plugins/Android folder. This might not be what you're looking for, but I'll be glad if this helps :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, I fixed it by fully removing the ExternalDependencyManager folder in the project and replaced it using the latest Jar Resolver plugin from here https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/external-dependency-manager-latest.unitypackage

At the same time I also installed Python 2.7 and added it to system path, but I'm pretty sure the jar resolver thing is what fixed the issue. The root problem is the embedded analytics (EditorMeasurement) fail and Firebase never executes the python scripts that make all the Plugins/Firebase/res/values xmls

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was happening after adding a new Firebase package with a version bigger than the other Firebase packages already in the project. Updating all the packages to the same version solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the editor folder inside the PlayServicesResolver folder and then reimporting it from any of the firebase unity packages.